# "Cannot subclass the final class" error, but the class is not final

Tags: java, inheritance, package, final-class

Here is my code:

```
package basic;

public abstract class Entity {}
```

---

```
package characters;

import basic.Entity;

public abstract class Character extends Entity {}
```

---

```
package player;

public class Player extends Character {}
```

I am getting the

> The type `Player` cannot subclass the `final class Character`.

but I checked a million times and I am yet to use `final` all but ONCE in my project. What gives?

Comment: The answer is already given. Here's a tip how to find it out using your IDE (e.g. Eclipse). Place the mouse over the ´Character´ word, and it'll show you that it's `java.lang.Character` and not `characters.Character`.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You are extending `java.lang.Character` (which does not need an import, as it comes from `java.lang`).

Insert `import characters.Character` into your `Player` code.

---

Reference: [using package members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html):

> For convenience, the Java compiler automatically imports two entire packages for each source file: (1) the java.lang package and (2) the current package (the package for the current file).

Comment: Instead, rename the custom `Character` class.

Answer (score 17):

Character is a class of java.lang (the wrapper class of "char").
you have to import characters.Character in your Player class

```
package player;
import characters.Character

public class Player extends Character {

}
```

Comment: A better suggestion would be to avoid doubling the names of default library classes in your code-base altogether.  Treat "Character" just as you would the keyword "char" since that's what it stands in for anyhow.  I'd say rename the "Character" class to "Avatar", "Entity", "Person" or something else that won't cause any confusion with existing default classes.

Answer (score 9):

In this case, I strongly recommend using [the fully qualified name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.7) of the `Character` class in [the `extends` clause](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4).

```
public class Player extends characters.Character {}
```

Experienced Java developers know that [`java.lang.Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html) is [`final`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.2) and can't thereby be extended. By writing `class Player extends Character`, you would probably make them nonplussed.

> Every compilation unit *implicitly imports* every public type name declared in the predefined package `java.lang`, as if the declaration `import java.lang.*;` appeared at the beginning of each compilation unit immediately after any package declaration. As a result, the names of all those types are available as *simple names* in every compilation unit.
>
> <sup>[Java 11 Specification > 7. Packages and Modules > 7.3. Compilation Units](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.3)</sup>

Of course, it would be more reasonable to pick up a name that doesn't collide with the classes from the standard `java.lang` package (like `Person`, or `GameCharacter`).

Answer (score 7):

**Character is a final class** as defined in Java Docs:

```
public final class Character
extends Object
implements Serializable, Comparable<Character>
```

so it cannot be sub-classed.

You are getting error from this Character class, which is being **implicitly** imported. **Beware!**.